# Transaction Serialization/Deserialization not matching

Tags: transactions, web3.js, deserialization

I'm trying to send a serialized transaction to a server, and then deserialize it there to be sent to an RPC then.

There's one `owner` account, and two types of instructions as mentioned:

- `NonWritableIx`: this instruction does **NOT** require `owner` to be `isWritable: true`
- `WritableIx`: this instruction does require `owner` to be `isWritable: true`

Now if a send a serialized `Transaction(NonWritableIx, WritableIx)`, and then deserialize it in the server, I notice that the `owner` account is marked as `isWritable: true` even for the `NonWritableIx`.

Whereas if I send a serialized `Transaction(NonWritableIx, NonWritableIx)`, then on deserialization, both instructions have `owner` as `isWritable: false`.

I'm assuming in the former case, the `isWritable` changes due to the presence of a `WritableIx`. But I was wondering if this is a desired behaviour?

The code snippet for serialization/deserialization is as shown below,

```
// Client
 const serialized = tx.serialize({
     requireAllSignatures: false,
 });

// Server
const serialized = request.body?.transaction;
if (typeof serialized !== 'string') throw new Error('invalid transaction');
let transaction = Transaction.from(Buffer.from(serialized, 'base64'));
```

Comment: In the sentence “Whereas if I send a serialized Transaction(NonWritableIx, WritableIx)” did you mean to write “Whereas if I send a serialized Transaction(NonWritableIx, NonWritableIx)”?

Comment: Ah yes, my bad I'll change that. Thanks @steveluscher!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a transaction is serialized, the writeable and signer bits are only stored once for each account, at their most promoted value as referenced by all instructions. This discards the individual instruction-specified values making it impossible to recover upon deserialization.

Comment: Does this have to do something with the creation of `new Set()` here, https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/e1567abf41c5746f00ccd18c52021b9d6c566bb9/src/transaction.ts#L642 ?

Comment: no. the rustdocs for [`MessageHeader`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/0d7d2090a2b7d97997a7a2a207b2bd0d4a5ecba5/sdk/program/src/message/mod.rs#L61-L110) explain it well